# A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected error while doing SVM?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am creating a SVM model with one independent variable X and dependent variable y.I performed feature scaling as both the data variable was not on same scale.

Now when i am training a model on dataset i am getting error as :

DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True).

Below are the code snippet from which i am getting error:

```
# Building Model on whole dataset

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)
```

Entire file:

```
# Importing Libraries

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# import data Set

dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

# Feature Scaling

y = y.reshape(len(y), 1)

# Feature Scaling

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Building Model on training dataset

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)
```

File on which i am training my model

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one feature (variable) so indeed the line `y = y.reshape(-1, 1)` is needed.

```
# Importing Libraries

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# import data Set

dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

y = y.reshape(-1, 1)

# Feature Scaling

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Building Model on training dataset

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)
```

Verify that the model was fitted:

```
regressor.get_params()

{'C': 1.0,
 'cache_size': 200,
 'coef0': 0.0,
 'degree': 3,
 'epsilon': 0.1,
 'gamma': 'scale',
 'kernel': 'rbf',
 'max_iter': -1,
 'shrinking': True,
 'tol': 0.001,
 'verbose': False}
```

The warning that you get is:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:73:
>   DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array
>   was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for
>   example using ravel().   return f(**kwargs)

and it is a `DataConversionWarning` that means that the algorithm did not converge successfully.

Comment: i just tried this but still i am getting error as :

raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  45000.   50000.   60000.   80000.  110000.  150000.  200000.  300000.
  500000. 1000000.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: please post a part of your data

Comment: i have posted the entire dataset in question above.

Comment: Thanks it worked with warning as you explained above :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
regressor.fit(X,y)
```

with this line:

```
regressor.fit(x,np.ravel(y,order="c"))
```